6 trees started from the same mulberry in a pot - all healthy for now
I picked some fresh mulberries from a tree at a friends house last April, and planted one berry in a 12" pot to see if it would grow. I now have 6 healthy trees very close together in the pot. I want to separate them and plant in different spots in my yard. Should I separate into other pots first, and after a season or so move them to the ground. Or, would I get a healthy set of trees if I just transplanted the whole pot's contents into one hole in the yard? What are the chances that the trees would live if separated into different pots? Should the separation be done in the fall when dormant?

A berry has many seeds, so you get many plants.
Now you should decide how many of them you want, as you see, it is easy to get new plants: remember that the mulberries are large plants, and they cause problems with rotten mulberries on ground, so do not put them to make shadow to cars or other stuffs you do not want to clean often (and before uses).
What do do, it is up to you. All solutions should work. By waiting, you risk to damage trunk (or the trunks get entangled or not strait). Also mulberries may make long root, which may cause problem to remove it from pot. In any case all low branches will be cut, so it is also not a huge no-no.
Personally I would separate them when the trees (seedlings) have few leaves. An old knife helps. Try to remove less soil as possible from roots (so the knife and other flat tools may help).
Early summer this year I needed to remove a now too large mulberry from my vineyard (also in this case, in reality there were more then one, birds or foxes seeded them). Because of long and strong roots, and my lack of time, I cut roots and did a bad job on removing the plants. I planted in an other place of my garden and disregarded watering, good soil, fertilizes). In few weeks all leaves got dry (but in one small plant): experiment almost failed, but now all trunks/branches got many new leaves. In short: it is much stronger as I expected, so I would not worry too much. So, you should not worry too much.

Thank  you for the advice. I have decided to wait until this fall, In E. Texas that will be late Oct or Nov. and separate them while dormant. They are about 12" - 16" tall right now. Interesting thing is, I have two different varieties growing from one berry. Two of the 6 have totally different shaped leaves than the other four. I have room for2 of them in my backyard, and one in front. I have a live oak tree planted to one day shade my cars. Is it best to do these things when the plant is dormant?
